# Django model with multiple choices

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I need to define that model 'Serie' has multiple category (action, adventure, ...). I saw that there's a field called Field.choices, but then the Serie would just have 1 category.

Should I define another model named 'Category' with the multiple categories and then set a Foreign Key on the Serie side to Category?

There is any other way doing that easier?

Thanks.

```
class Serie (models.Model):
    serie_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="covers")
    serie_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    #Category needed

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.serie_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is Create a separate Model called `Category` and put the `category` as ManyToMany field in the `Serie` model. in this way, you can filtering and the searching query will be easier.